# Replacing the last word of a line only if match string found

Tags: unix, sed

I want to replace the last word of the line only if a matching string found.

Input file :

```
 "id": 5918915, 

 "description": "Test Job - NA", 

 "revision": 5
```

Expected output :

```
 "id": 5918915, 

 "description": "Test Job - EU", 

 "revision": 5
```

So, for lines matching `description`, replace the last word with given word. In this case, in line 2 replace last word `NA",` with `EU",`

I tried

```
sed -i '/"description"/s/.*/EU",//g' file_name
```

but it is not working

Comment: I was trying sed command something like this sed -i '/"description"/s/.*/EU",//g' file_name but it is not working. So looking for proper sed command

Comment: please update the question the commands you tried.

Comment: Are you set on using `sed` for this, or might other tools be an option?  Also, that input data looks a little like incomplete JSON. Are you *actually* dealing with json, or is this some other recognized format? Or something custom?

Comment: @ghoti ..Yes I am trying to update the JSON file and as I am writing a shell script sed is my familiar option. Anyway I got the working command
sed -i '/"description"/ s/[^ ]* *$/EI",/'  file_name

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i -r '/^[ \t]*"description":.*/s/^(.* )NA",[\t ]*$/\1EU/'  FILE

 "id": 5918915, 
 "description": "Test Job - EU",
 "revision": 5"
```

<sub>For testing, remove the -i switch.</sub>

The amount of whitespace isn't quiet clear, so I placed `[ \t]*` at line start and end for blanks and tabs of random size.

Your command:

```
  sed -i '/"description"/s/.*/EU",//g' file_name
```

should substitute the whole line with `EU",`, not just the last char sequence.

The -i is an option of GNU-sed. Check your version and read the fine manual. If your sed lacks support, you have to redirect the output to a file `sed "COMMANDS" INFILE > TMPFILE; mv TMPFILE INFILE`. Note, that `sed "COMMANDS" INFILE > INFILE` will not work, but destroy the INFILE immediately; a popular, clever, but disfunctional idea. I had it too. :)

Comment: could simplify.. for ex: `/"description"/ s/[^ ]* *$/EU",/` (replace space with `[:blank:]` if needed)

Comment: What's simpler about that?

Comment: Thanks Guys,
I got the working command
sed -i '/"description"/ s/[^ ]* *$/EU",/'  file_name

Comment: @Ankur: Yes, you need the -i for persistent changes, not just in the output, and without parenthesis, you don't need -r.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this usage of `-i` is specific to GNU sed, and is unlikely to work on other platforms (macOS, *BSD, SVR4, etc). If you could update your answer to be platform-agnostic, it would certainly help future generations. :-)

Comment: @ghoti: Added a sed -i disclaimer. Fine? I'm very tired of putting this and similar disclaimers below every second text. Isn't there a premanufactured shortcut, like `[mcve]`? I should ask it on meta? Later, I promise ....

Comment: I don't think you can get a tag-specific shortcut. This should arguably be spelled out more clearly in the [Stack Overflow `sed` tag info page](/tags/sed/info) and it should be easier to link to that.

Answer (score 1):

I got the working command

```
sed -i '/"description"/ s/[^ ]* *$/EU",/' file_name
```