# Find pattern in line and find last word, if matches write line and previous one to file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

Looking for lines which start with "DESC:", find last word and if it matches: write line and previous one to another file

I read this [Replacing the last word of a line only if match string found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927083/replacing-the-last-word-of-a-line-only-if-match-string-found) but unfortunately

I have a long text file in which 2 consecutive lines belongs together: one with the file path and the next one with a description, like f.i.:

```
PATH: /all movies/DE/0051.mkv
DESC: Bloodshot German
PATH: /all movies/DE/0052.mkv
DESC: Birds of Prey German
PATH: /all movies/EN/0074.mkv
DESC: Army of One English
```

So actually, if the last word matches in a line which starts with "DESC:" then write line and previous one to another file.

I now use a 'while read loop', but that is so slow.

```
DIR="c:/all movies/"
FILE1="${DIR}/movies_GE.txt"; echo "MOVIES GERMAN"  > ${FILE1)
FILE2="${DIR}/movies_EN.txt"; echo "MOVIES ENGLISH" > ${FILE2)

while read LINE1; do
  if [[ ${LINE1:0:4} = "PATH:" ]]; then
    read LINE2
    if [[ ${LINE2:0:4} = "DESC:" ]]; then
      LASTWORD=`awk '{print $NF}' <<< ${LINE2}`
      if grep -iq "German"  <<< ${LASTWORD}; then echo ${LINE1} >> ${FILE1}; echo ${LINE2} >> ${FILE1}; fi
      if grep -iq "English" <<< ${LASTWORD}; then echo ${LINE1} >> ${FILE2}; echo ${LINE2} >> ${FILE2}; fi
    fi
  fi
done < ${DIR}/all movies/movies_ALL.txt
```

Is there a (much) better/faster solution f.i. with sed?

I tried:

```
sed -ir '/^"DESC:":.*/s/^(.* )German$//g'  ${FILE1}
sed -ir '/^"DESC:":.*/s/^(.* )English$//g' ${FILE2}
```

Comment: `sed` can't redirect lines to different files. Use `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v dir=/some/dir '
BEGIN{
   # provide mapping: last word -> filename to write to
   files["English"] = dir "movies_EN.txt"
   files["German"] = dir "movies_DE.txt"
}
# remember path
/^PATH: /{path=$0}
# when desc
/^DESC: /{
   # extract last word
   w=$0; gsub(/ *$/, "", w); gsub(/.* /, "", w);
   # write to one of files, if exsits
   if (w in files) {
       printf "%s\n%s", $0, path >> files[w]
   }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ne 'N;/\nDESC/{/.*German$/w file1' -e '/.*English/w file2' -e '};D' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`.

Maintain a two line window.

If the second line begins `DESC` and the last word is either `German` or `English`, write to file1 or file2.

Delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused about the D  (delete first line) which I didn't understand, but it is deleting in the pattern space and not a physical line ;) How can I make it all case-insentive? I tried i.s.o. using '/w', to use '/iw' or '/Iw', but unfortunately

Comment: @ni_hao in GNU sed you can add the `I` flag to match case-insensitive i.e `sed -ne 'N;/\nDESC/I{/.*German$/Iw file1' -e '/.*English/Iw file2' -e '};D' file`

Comment: Thanks, I was using it at a device where sed is part of busybox v1.24.1 and that does not support the -I parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Awk would be a better candidate for this:

```
awk '/^PATH/ { path=$0 } /^DESC/ && /English$/ { printf "%s\n%s",$0,path  }' file > newfile
```

If the line starts with "PATH", set a variable path to the line ($0). Then when the line starts with "DESC" and the line ends with "English", print the line and path to newfile

Comment: Thanks, but the written file will be 0 bytes; so nothing written.

Comment: The solution works locally with the test data posted. What version of awk do you have?

Comment: I'm guessing the input has DOS line feeds, and thus doesn't match `/English$/`. Try `/English\r?$/` or fix the file (it's not a valid text file anyway; don't use Windows editors, or in fact Windows at all).

Comment: So does it work with the line endings corrected?

Comment: It works but not good: I have a file with multiple lines starting with 'PATH:" followed by a 'DESC:' line and not only 'German' or 'English' in the 'DESC:'-line. It will find (and write almost all lines to a file as espected, but every time the first found right line with 'PATH:' will not be written. So if I have f.i. this: ```PATH: /all movies/DE/0043.mkv
DESC: Mon amour French
PATH: /all movies/DE/0052.mkv
DESC: Birds of Prey German.``` It starts writing with 'DESC: Birds of Prey German' and thus not the previous 'PATH:'-line

Comment: I am using grep now: ```grep -iB 1 'DESC:.*German[[:cntrl:]]*$' ${FILE1}```